# Using Nogokiri to parse HTML in Ruby

Tags: html, ruby

I am trying to parse an HTML file using Nokogiri in Ruby. What would be the correct call to save the number 2882524 to a variable. Below is the HTML snippet where the number is.

```
<td class="m_7818752582546518432m_-7154585397242854273small-12 m_7818752582546518432m_-7154585397242854273large-3 m_7818752582546518432m_-7154585397242854273text-body" style="border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:'Roboto-Regular',sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:normal;letter-spacing:0;line-height:20px;margin:0;padding:0 8px;width:129px;word-wrap:break-word" align="left" valign="top">
    2882524
  </td>
```

Comment: `Nokogiri::HTML(snippet).text.to_i`, assuming your "snippet" is the document.

Comment: Well the snippet is just part of the entire HTML document. I save the document like this. html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(params[:html]). How do I get that number from the entire HTML document?

Comment: Then `node.text.to_i`, where `node` is the `<td>` node. Without knowing the rest of the document, we can't tell you how to get to it (except trivially "use `#at_css` or `#at_xpath` methods).

Comment: How would I be able to figure out the exact line of code. My HTML is fairly large.

Comment: By identifying how that element differs from any other (in position, structure or content), then specifying an XPath or CSS selector to fetch it. I doubt it is the only element in your document with the class `m_7818752582546518432m_-7154585397242854273small-12` (or any of the listed classes), so only that is not enough to identify it. It's also probably not the only element that is vertical-aligned to `top`, or aligned to `left`. Now, if you know it's e.g. the third `<td>` in a `<table>` with a certain ID, you can start doing something about it.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ “Please code the solution for me for free” is not an allowed type of questions on SO. Please show your effort and where you got stuck. Downvoted until a question is corrected.

Comment: @Amadan There are a bunch of nested tables, tbodies, td, and tr. How would I go about figuring out the exact way to get the number I want. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question because nobody knows the structure of your document. @Amadan has shown you main principles

Comment: I'll consider answering your question as soon as you explain to me satisfactorily how I can get to my drumming practice the fastest (without knowing where I am, where my drumming practice is, or downloading any maps of the city I live in). What I can tell you is, there's a bunch of streets, and also train lines.

Answer (score 0):

html file  = /home/raj/test.html

```
<td class="m_7818752582546518432m_-7154585397242854273small-12 m_7818752582546518432m_-7154585397242854273large-3 m_7818752582546518432m_-7154585397242854273text-body" style="border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:'Roboto-Regular',sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:normal;letter-spacing:0;line-height:20px;margin:0;padding:0 8px;width:129px;word-wrap:break-word" align="left" valign="top">
    2882524
  </td>
```

Tried in irb of ruby version 2.6.1 as,

```
2.6.1 :026 > require 'nokogiri'
 => true 
2.6.1 :027 > doc = Nokogiri::HTML(File.open('/home/raj/test.html'))
 => #<Nokogiri::HTML::Document:0x2ac37b6e06a4 name="document" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::DTD:0x2ac37b6e02a8 name="html">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2ac37b703d5c name="html" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2ac37b703a28 name="body" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2ac37b7037e4 name="td" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x2ac37b70376c name="class" value="m_7818752582546518432m_-7154585397242854273small-12 m_7818752582546518432m_-7154585397242854273large-3 m_7818752582546518432m_-7154585397242854273text-body">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x2ac37b703758 name="style" value="border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:'Roboto-Regular',sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:normal;letter-spacing:0;line-height:20px;margin:0;padding:0 8px;width:129px;word-wrap:break-word">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x2ac37b703744 name="align" value="left">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x2ac37b703730 name="valign" value="top">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2ac37b7027b8 "\n    2882524\n  ">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2ac37b702484 "\n">]>]>]> 


2.6.1 :034 > doc.text
 => "\n    2882524\n  \n" 
2.6.1 :035 > doc.text.strip
 => "2882524"
```